# Order of operations for matrix algebra

Tags: matrices, transpose

$A$ and $B$ are matrices.  I need to evaluate $A-BB^T$, where $B^T$ is $B$ transpose.  I'm just confused on the order of operations.  My thoughts are:

1. find $B^T$
2. multiply $B$ and $B^T$
3. subtract that product from $A$

Is this order correct?

Comment: Yes.  Just as with scalars:  unitary operations then multiplication then addition.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The order of operations is exactly the same as it is with numbers.

Comment: If you think about $B^T$ as a sort of exponentiation (just notation-wise, it clearly isn't), then the order of operations should be more intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

Yes, as pointed out in the comments, this is correct.